# Spring Integration Asynchronous error handling

Tags: spring, spring-integration

In Spring integration, I have the to deal with dynamic channels creation but when I debug the application I am seeing a “blocking” problem between different channels.

In order  to obtain the dynamic channels, I divided the application in parent/children contexts and I have the following Spring integration infrastructure:

```
Gateway (parent) --> Transformer(Parent) --> Router (Parent/Child) --> TCP outbound (child)
```

This configuration works fine when all the TCP connections are OK. For testing purposes, I am stopping the different servers where the clients are connected and I could see how the `errorChannel` only receives errors (connection refused) but the rest of the adapters are also stopped. I would like to redirect/discard/separate these error and avoid the propagation to the common `errorChannel`.

I understand the `errorChannel` is a common channel, shared in the parent context but how can I develop a complete separated scenario for each child context?. Is the common Gateway the problem?

I see the post [Error handling in Spring integration flow async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38911968/error-handling-in-spring-integration-flow-async)  but I have a complete separated environment for each child and I would like to take the advantage of these dynamic separation. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add another gateway in each child with its own error channel.

```
--> Router (Parent/Child) -> service-activator (child) -> gateway(child) -> TCP Out.
```

The gateway service interface needs a `void` return because no reply is expected.

Comment: This was really helpful.